# Django: Getting "Page not found" Error While Using Slug in URL

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am a beginner learning `Django` through a building an `app`, called `PhoneReview`. It will store reviews related to the latest mobile phone. It will also display phone brands, along with the associated phone models and their reviews.

Right now, I am facing an error just after I have added codes to use `slug` in the `URLs`. When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index`, I see this page: 
[image]

When I click on "Samsung," I get this **error**:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/samsung/
Raised by:  PhoneReview.views.ModelView
No phone model found matching the query

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

I have successfully performed migration. But still, I am facing the issue. 
Here are my codes of **models.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturing_since = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.brand_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class PhoneModel(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    launch_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.model_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Review(models.Model):
    phone_model = models.ManyToManyField(PhoneModel, related_name='reviews')
    review_article = models.TextField()
    date_published = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    link = models.TextField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.review_article
```

Here are my codes of **urls.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'PhoneReview'

urlpatterns = [
    path('index', views.BrandListView.as_view(), name='brandlist'),
    path('index/<slug:slug>/', views.ModelView.as_view(), name='modellist'),
    path('details/<slug:slug>/', views.ReviewView.as_view(), name='details'),
]
```

Here are my codes of **views.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from .models import Brand, PhoneModel, Review


class BrandListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_brands'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Brand.objects.all()


class ModelView(generic.DetailView):
    model = PhoneModel
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/phonemodel.html'
    context_object_name = 'phonemodel'

class ReviewView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Review
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/details.html'
```

Here are my codes of **apps.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class PhonereviewConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'PhoneReview'
```

Here are my codes of **index.html** located inside templates folder:

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title%}
Brand List
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!--Page content-->
<h1>This is Brand List Page</h1>
<h2>Here is the list of the brands</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for brand in all_brands %}
<!--            <li>{{ brand.brand_name }}</li>-->
            <li><a href = "{% url 'PhoneReview:modellist' brand.slug %}">{{ brand.brand_name }}</a></li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
<img src="{% static "images/brandlist.jpg" %}" alt="Super Mario Odyssey" /> <!-- New line -->
{% endblock %}
```

Here are my codes of **phonemodel.html** located inside templates folder:

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title%}
Phone Model Page
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!--Page content-->
<h1>This is Phone Model Page</h1>
<h2>Here is the phone model</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href = "{% url 'PhoneReview:details' details.slug %}">{{ phonemodel.model_name }}</a></li>
    </ul>
<img src="{% static "images/brandlist.jpg" %}" alt="Super Mario Odyssey" /> <!-- New line -->
{% endblock %}
```

Here are my codes of **details.html** located inside templates folder:

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">


<html lang="en">

{% block title%}Details{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1>This is the Details Page</h1>

<h2>Review:</h2>
<p>{{ review.review_article }}</p>

<h2>News Link:</h2>
<p>{{ review.link }}</p>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

I feel that I have made a mistake on either index.html or phonemodel.html. But being a beginner, I can't catch it.

How can I fix the issue?

**Update:** I added the following codes in phonemodel.html to loop over phone models, as suggested by @c.grey :

```
<ul>
    {% for model_name in all_model_name %}
        <li><a href = "{% url 'PhoneReview:details' details.slug %}">{{ phonemodel.model_name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Also, I added this line in index.html:

```
<li><a href = "{% url 'PhoneReview:modellist' phonemodel.slug %}">{{ brand.brand_name }}</a></li>
```

Moreover, I added these codes in views.py:

```
class ModelView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/phonemodel.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_model_name'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return PhoneModel.objects.all()
```

But now, I am getting this error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'modellist' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['index/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

Here is the link to my project files:
https://github.com/shawnmichaels583583/phoneradar

Comment: Try `'index/<slug>/'` instead of `'index/<slug:slug>/'` in the urls.

Comment: can you show full error traceback

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve: When clicking on a brand (Samsung), what do you want to show? Now it seems you're trying to show the detail view for one specific model, but doesn't the brand page show the *list* of all phones? i.e. it should point to a ListView that you haven't created.

Comment: @Clarity It doesn't work. I still get the same error.

Comment: @dirkgroten When I click on brand (Samsung), I am supposed to be taken to the phonemodel.html, page where all the phone models of Samsung, like Galaxy S10, will be displayed. When I click on Galaxy S10, I am supposed to be taken to the details.html page, which will have the review of the specific phone model (Galaxy S10), along with a link.

Comment: But the view `ModelView` you're using for displaying phonemodel.html is a `DetailView` (the purpose of which is to show **one** model). You should make it a `ListView` and set the queryset to filter the phones by brand.

Comment: @dirkgroten OK. I understand. Right now, displaying only one model should work fine. When I used `<pk>` instead of `<slug:slug>` in url.py, and `id` instead `slug` in index.html and phonemodel.html, everything was working fine. But the problem begins when I attempt to add slug in URL. Nonetheless, can you help me to solve the issue while displaying only one phone model, like Galaxy S10? Can you give me the working codes? It will be highly appreciated. I am really stuck here.

Comment: It worked with `id` by coincidence (because you probably have a brand with id = 1 and a phone with id = 1, for example). `{% url 'PhoneReview:modellist' brand.slug %}` is passing a `brand.slug` to a view to display a phone. You need to pass it a phone slug. But to get a phone slug, you need to loop through all the phones for that brand first, which you don't do anywhere. So you need to create a list view for your brand, as I mentioned above. Or inside the brand loop, add another loop `{{ for phone in brand.phonemodel_set.all }}` and then you can use `phone.slug`.

Comment: @dirkgroten Can you share the codes through the answer section?

Comment: @dirkgroten Would you please take a look at the updated description? I have looped through the phones. But I am getting an error.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you are passing **Brand model slug** to get **PhoneModel model data**.

To get details from PhoneModel you need to pass PhoneModel slug to get data

Comment: Are you telling me to replace `{% url 'PhoneReview:modellist' brand.slug %}` to `{% url 'PhoneReview:modellist' phonemodel.slug %}`?

Comment: Yes, but you are looping over brands, so you must also loop over phone models

Comment: When I add the aforementioned code, I can't get to the index page. It gives error.

Comment: Would you please give me the codes? As I am beginner, it will be really helpful.

Comment: Also, should I upload the compressed version of the project file on Google Drive and share the link with you so that you can see everything there?

Comment: I added the following codes in phonemodel.html to loop over phone models: `<ul>
        {% for model_name in all_model_name %}
            <li><a href = "{% url 'PhoneReview:details' details.slug %}">{{ phonemodel.model_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>`. But now, I am getting this error `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'modellist' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['index/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that your link points to `brand.slug` (here `samsung`) but it seems to me that you don't have any phone model whose name is just `samsung`, do you?

You mix up brands and phone models

Comment: Not really. I added Samsung through Django admin.

Comment: If you want to check, list the modelPhones in your db using `python manage.py shell` and then `PhoneModel.objects.all()`

Comment: I typed `python manage.py` shell and then 1PhoneModel.objects.all()` on PyCharm terminal. I get this error, `NameError: name 'PhoneModel' is not defined`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it does not load the models. Follow this tutorial to import `PhoneModel` and then fetch all models : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api

Comment: When updating your question, please add the new lines in the previous code, it's hard to know where you added code. Nevertheless, I think you have the right syntax for `index.html` but I don't know if you defined the variable `phonemodel ` in your Jenga template. Please let us see the new whole `index.html` code.